# 2013 Search Settings > Configure Search Navigation > Change Search Parameter

Tags: 2013, search

I want to update the search dropdown for one of my sites so that it can search google (as an example) for one of the options.

Right now I can enter http://google.com for the URL without any issue. When I run the search it generates the URL:
https://www.google.com/?k=TEST

I need it to generate the URL:
https://www.google.com/#q=TEST.

[image]

**Question**
Is there a way to add a token or modify the URL in a way so I can insert q instead of a k for the search term parameter?

Comment: Nice question, RWL01! It can be done using [window.location.replace(...)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/286244)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but unfortunately SharePoint does not allow me to put any value that does not look like a URL (relative or absolute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 I would do this with a Result Source using Open Search against Google. (I have done this with Bing and MSDN for different portals, I expect that Google supports Open Search).

1. Create a new Result Source and choose Open Search.
2. I found a link for Google News, but don't have one for regular Google. `http://news.google.com/news?hl=en-us&amp;ned=us&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;q={searchTerms}&amp;output=rss` Here is the format for Bing `http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}&format=rss`You can download examples from SharePoint 2010 and just strip out the URLs [from MSDN](http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?q=search%20connector)
3. Leave the credentials as anonymous.

Next you have to choose how to employ it. You can create a new search page, add an additional web part, or (my preference) add a Query Rule that sends the users query to the Result Source.

1. Create a new query rule on Local SharePoint Results
2. Determine what will trip your rule (or remove the condition to always run it.) For example, if I have an MSDN rule I may choose to run it when I detect the action term "KB".
3. Add a Result Block and select your new Result Source and the parameter for "Search this Source".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like my method was not an enterprise solution and lacked the sophistication needed. My takeaway is that it's possible but I will need to depend on result sources for searches of this nature.

Comment: I believe you are correct.